# Synchronous use of database insertion

Tags: java, mysql, synchronous

I have created a java application that is inserting data to a mysql database. Under some conditions, i need to post some of these data via email, using a java application that I will write as well.
My problem is that i am not sure how i should implement this.

From what I understand, I could use a UDF inside MySql to execute a java application, for which there are many against opinions into using it. Let alone that both the database and the mail client application will reside in a VM that i dont have admin access, and dont want to install anything that neither me nor the admin knows.

My other alternative, that I can think of, is to set up the mail client (or some other application), to run every minute just to check for newly inserted data. Is this a better aproach? Isn't it going to use resources for doing almost nothing. At the moment the VM might not be heavily loaded, but i have no idea how many applications there might end up running on the same machine.

Is there any other alternative i should consider using?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to consider the speed of internet, database server load, system resources. If you have enough memory and less load to insert data in databases or database load is not so much then you can approach this by cron setup. For linux call a script for every 5 minutes. The script perform the following-

```
1. Fetch unread Emails as files
3. Perfrom shell script to read needed data.
3. write data to mysql
4. Delete the email
```

If you have heavy loaded system then wise you need to do this once or twice in an hour or may vary.

Comment: thats what i mean to run the mail client every minute, or 5. but isnt this just a waste of resources?

Comment: @SkarosIlias  it doesn't take much of system resources, its like lightweight background processes. But if frequency of emails are high then mail client run with 2 minutes or something.

Comment: @SkarosIlias and its also does matter that, how much time taken by database server perform insert data.